# java polymorphism with generics

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I'm trying to do a factory with devices depending on a `fileName` with the appropriate device corresponding to it.

My first intuitive approach to avoid creating instance was to define static methods to validate the fileName into its different classes, let's say `MyDevice1.validFilePath(fileName)  return new MyDevice()` but it seems that its not possible to force the implementation of a static method from the `Device` ancestor.

So I went for polymorphism, and surprise, it seems that compiler complains because he cannot convert `MyDevice` to `Device<Number>`. What should I do? Polymorphism applies at compilation because `MyDevice` is a valid class, but `MyDevice` cannot be a `Device<Number>`?

```
public abstract class device<T extends Number>{
    
    protected List<T> samples;

    public abstract boolean validFileName(String fileName);

}

public class MyDevice extends device<Double>{

    public boolean validFileName(String fileName){
        return fileName.contains("MyDevice");
    }
}

public class DeviceFactory{

    public static Device<Number> getDevice(String fileName){
        Device<Number> res;
        MyDevice md = new MyDevice();
        if (md.validFileName(fileName)){
            res = md;// invalid??!!!
        }else{
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    
        return res;
    }

}
```

It seems that changing the `Device<Number>` with `Device` passes at compilation, but complaining about `Device is a raw type. References to generic type Device<T> should be parameterized`. Should I just ignore this error in that case? What is the way to go?

Comment: If you return a `MyDevice`, why not make that your return type? `MyDevice` isn't a `Device<Number>`, it's a `Device<Double>`, which is a `Device<? extends Number>`.

Comment: A `Device<Double>` is not a `Device<Number>`. It *is* a `Device<? extends Number>`, so you could use that if you wanted.

Comment: @khelwood that is the answer I was looking for `Device<? extends Number>`!! Thank you very much, that deserves an answer...